# Member is inaccessible

Tags: c++, friend

```
class Example{
public:
    friend void Clone::f(Example);
    Example(){
        x = 10;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

class Clone{
public:
    void f(Example ex){
        std::cout << ex.x;
    }
};
```

When I write f as a normal function, the program compiles successful. However, when I write f as a class member, this error occurs.

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Ehm..... **What error?**

Comment: Here is the screenshot: http://s2.postimg.org/lbjt37f0p/Untitled.png

Comment: Forget intellisense. Did you actually try *compiling* this, and in so doing, see the *first* error? [**Is this**](http://ideone.com/6uTyS2) what you're *really* trying to do?

Comment: Here is how it looks after I compile the program: http://s28.postimg.org/sx85t9lm5/Untitled.png

Comment: @Khanh Exactly, now look at how [**this** is different](http://ideone.com/6uTyS2).

Comment: I didn't know that missing the prototype would cause the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing is not a root-cause compilation error. It is an artifact of a different problem. You're friending to a member function of a class the compiler has no earthly clue even exists yet,much less exists with that specific member.

A `friend` declaration of a non-member function has the advantage where it also acts as a prototype declaration. Such is *not* the case for a member function. The compiler must know that (a) the class exists, and (b) the member exists.

Compiling your original code (I use clang++ v3.6), the following errors are *actually* reported:

```
main.cpp:6:17: Use of undeclared identifier 'Clone'
main.cpp:17:25: 'x' is a private member of 'Example'
```

The former is a direct cause of the latter. But doing *this* instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Example;

class Clone
{
public:
    void f(Example);
};

class Example
{
public:
    friend void Clone::f(Example);
    Example()
    {
        x = 10;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

void Clone::f(Example ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.x;
};

int main()
{
    Clone c;
    Example e;
    c.f(e);   
}
```

**Output**

```
10
```

This does the following:

- Forward declares `Example`
- Declares `Clone`, but does not implement `Clone::f` (yet)
- Declares `Example`, thereby making `x` known to the compiler.

  - Friends `Clone::f` to `Example`
- Implements `Clone::f`

At each stage we provide what the compiler needs to continue on.

Best of luck.